# How to use result of first KQL query in the second query to filter results?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a first KQL query that returns a list of domain names, and then I want to use these to filter another KQL query. I just can't figure out the syntax to do it. Is there a way to use the contains() operator with a for loop/iteration in KQL?

KQL - Query 1

```
    let hostnames = () {
    AllDomains 
    | where hostname !contains "default.com" and hostname != ""
    | distinct hostname
   }
```

KQL - Query 2

```
let start_date = ago(10m);
let end_date = now();
LogEvents 
| where env_time between (start_date .. end_date)
| where headers  contains "X-Forwarded-For"
| where queryString contains (hostnames()) //This is what is needed to filter on all the domains from first query.
| project queryString
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please provide sample data + required results as datatable / in CSV format.

Answer (score 1):

this could work:

```
let hostnames =
    AllDomains 
    | where isnotempty(hostname) and hostname !has "default.com"
    | distinct hostname
;
let start_date = ago(10m);
let end_date = now();
LogEvents 
| where env_time between (start_date .. end_date)
| where headers contains "X-Forwarded-For"
| where queryString has_any (hostnames)
| project queryString
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you'll provide a sample of how your data looks and what you are trying to accomplish, but I think that instead of `contains` you'd want to use [`has_any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/has-anyoperator)